# Map the service running at a port to a subdomain

Tags: subdomain, mqtt, ubuntu-server

I have an MQTT broker running on my Ubuntu Server at port 1883 and a website running at port 80. I want to map my broker to broker.abc.com while my website to www.abc.com. What are the possible steps toward this problem?
Until now, I have tried to add a subdomain broker.mqtt.com in my GoDaddy control panel but it never worked.
For now, I can access my website and broker both at abc.com but I want to separate both of them.

Answer (score 1):

This can be possible if you use 2 load balancer with 2 domain name, for this kind of problem AWS introduce Wildcards (means one hosted zone in Route 53 and you have subdomains related to that). Like abc.com will be your hosted zone and broker.abc.com, website.abc.com will be wildcards.

So One of the Load balancers will redirect your broker.abc.com to port no 1883 and other Loadbalancer will redirect to port no 80.

Your wildcards(subdomains) will be mapped to loadblancer.